# создать метод который принимает лямбду

Tags: c#

как в метод Filter передать var evens = a.Filter(x => x % 2 == 0);

```
public static List<int> Filter(this List<int> even)
{
    return even;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var evens = a.Filter(x => x % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static List<int> Filter(this List<int> even, Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
...
}
```

Comment: отчего бы не использовать[`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @tym32167 можно и его